# How to stop mousemove() from executing when the element under the mouse moves?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this piece of code from a fellow SO user:

```
   $("#rightSubMenu").mousemove(function(e){
      console.log('executed');
      var h = $('#rightSubMenuScroller').height()+13;
      var offset = $($(this)).offset();
      var position = (e.pageY-offset.top)/$(this).height();
      if(position<0.33) {
         $(this).stop().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
      }
      else if(position>0.66) {
         $(this).stop().animate({ scrollTop: h }, 2000);
      }
      else
      {
         $(this).stop();
      }
   });
```

What it does, basically, is that it moves `#rightSubMenuScroller`, which is inside `#rightSubMenu`, whenever you hover over rightSubMenu. The problem is that with every pixel moved, it executes the whole function again resulting in a laggy animation.

When I activate the scrolling and move the mouse away from the element, the animation is nice.

I need to fix the code so that it doesn't lag. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) at the end of this event call.

```
$("#rightSubMenu").mousemove(function(e){
  // You code...
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will prevent the event bubbling up the DOM tree.

Alternatively and depending on your DOM structure, try [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) which keeps all other event handlers executing.

Answer (score 2):

look at it now: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Q9j/6/